# How to delete multiple rows in a QTableView widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to delete rows in a QTableView widget by pressing a QPushButton. The code works fine with a single row, however, when I select multiple rows one row is always left out.

This is what I have so far:

**main.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>350</width>
    <height>239</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="formLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>341</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnPopulate">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Populate Table</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
      <property name="selectionBehavior">
       <enum>QAbstractItemView::SelectRows</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnDelete">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Delete Row(s)</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QComboBox, QApplication, QHeaderView

class GUI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(dirname,'main.ui'), self)
        # buttons
        self.btnPopulate.clicked.connect(self.populate)
        self.btnDelete.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        # table model
        self.header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
        self.QSModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.QSModel.setColumnCount(3)
        self.QSModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.header)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.QSModel)
        self.tableView.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        
    def populate(self):
        row = self.QSModel.rowCount()
        for x in range(7):
            self.QSModel.insertRow(row)
            self.QSModel.setData(self.QSModel.index(row, 0), 'data' + str(x))
            self.QSModel.item(row, 0).setEditable(True)
            self.QSModel.setData(self.QSModel.index(row, 1), 'data' + str(x))
            self.QSModel.item(row, 1).setEditable(True)
            self.QSModel.setData(self.QSModel.index(row, 2), 'data' + str(x))
            self.QSModel.item(row, 1).setEditable(True) 

    def delete(self):
        if self.tableView.selectionModel().hasSelection():
            indexes = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedRows() 
            for index in sorted(indexes):
                print('Deleting row %d...' % index.row())
                self.QSModel.removeRow(index.row())
        else:
            print('No row selected!')
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've got the following questions:

1. Why is always one row not deleted when I select multiple rows and what do I need to change to delete all selected rows?
2. How do I automatically select the next row after the deletion is complete so that I could delete the whole table by repeatedly clicking the Delete Row(s) button?
3. Is there a built-in method that allows me to either connect the QPushButton or its action to DEL/BACKSPACE key-presses? I.e., I want DEL/BACKSPACE key-presses to trigger delete().

Comment: check my answer, but remember SO is a place where it is a question by post, questions 1 and 2 are very similar and can be taken as a question, but the third seems to be too far away, although this time I have answered it is about the next one to not get away from your initial question.

Comment: For your delete function, reverse your sorted index list and it should work. `for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True)` If you delete the rows in their natural order, after you delete row 1, row 2's index becomes 1.  If they are reversed it doesn't matter because the only indexes that are affected are after your last row to be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is always one row not deleted when I select multiple rows and what
>   do I need to change to delete all selected rows?

The problem is caused by removing a row by resetting the positions, for example, say that you remove 3,4,5, first remove 3, then 4 becomes 3, and 5 becomes 4, then you eliminate 4, remove the 4 current so that the initial 4 is not deleted.

`QModelIndex` are temporary indexes that are not notified if the positions change, instead `QPersistentModelIndex` if they are notified so you must use them to get the row even if it changes.

```
def delete(self):
    if self.tableView.selectionModel().hasSelection():
        indexes =[QPersistentModelIndex(index) for index in self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedRows()]
        for index in indexes:
            print('Deleting row %d...' % index.row())
            self.QSModel.removeRow(index.row())
    else:
        print('No row selected!')
```

> How do I automatically select the next row after the deletion is
>   complete so that I could delete the whole table by repeatedly clicking
>   the Delete Row(s) button?

to select a new row you must set some item of that row as active through the `setCurrentIndex()` method of `QTableView`, in this example I calculate the last row and with that I get the `QPersistentModelIndex` of an item of the next row, after deleting I convert it to `QModelIndex` and I use it in the previous method.

```
def delete(self):
    if self.tableView.selectionModel().hasSelection():
        indexes =[QPersistentModelIndex(index) for index in self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedRows()]
        maxrow = max(indexes, key=lambda x: x.row()).row()
        next_ix = QPersistentModelIndex(self.QSModel.index(maxrow+1, 0))
        for index in indexes:
            print('Deleting row %d...' % index.row())
            self.QSModel.removeRow(index.row())
        self.tableView.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex(next_ix))
    else:
        print('No row selected!')
```

> Is there a built-in method that allows me to either connect the
>   QPushButton or its action to DEL/BACKSPACE key-presses? I.e., I want
>   DEL/BACKSPACE key-presses to trigger delete().

to get the keyboard events you must overwrite the `keyPressEvent` method, this event happens as a `QKeyEvent` object that has a key method that returns the key pressed, verify if it is the desired key and if it is, then call `delete()`

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Backspace, Qt.Key_Delete):
        self.delete()
    QDialog.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your very detailed and helpful answer!!! 

I'll try to stay on topic in the future.